# List the fields associated with a record in ext.js

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs-stores

I have a bit of ext.js code that looks like:

```
items: [

    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        hidden: false,
        fieldLabel: 'MyType',
        inputId: 'MyType',
        bind: {
            value: '{MyType}'
        }
    }                
]
```

On the page the text that's displayed is:

```
[object Object]
```

I can't figure out how to see what the properties of this object are.

In the console if I do a

```
document.getElementById('MyType').value.__proto__
```

I see:

```
String { "" }
```

Comment: I guess this is a viewModel binding. I would suggest you do a lookup in the viewModel. Get a reference to the component and call getViewModel(). It can be either a value, formula or store.

Answer (score 0):

If MyType is an instance of Ext.data.Model you can see what fields are in the model with console.log("MyType data: %o", MyType.data);

The bind functionality requires a get and set for the value.  So if MyType had a config value of blaBla then the class system would automatically create a getter and setter for blaBla.  you could then bind value to {MyType.blaBla}

if MyType is a model and it has a field named "xyzPdq" then you can bind to {MyType.xyzPdq}